# .NET Maui with VS 2022 Preview - some packages can't be found

Tags: visual-studio-2022, maui

Hello I would like to try out .net maui, but I can't build a new .net Maui solution. I get a few errors where some packages can't be found.

- Unable to find package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration with version (>= 6.0.1-mauipre.1.216027.7)
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection wiht version (>= 6.0.1-mauipre.1.21602.7)
  etc.

Does anybody have the same issue?

Thanks for help

Comment: Did you update from an earlier version of VS 2022? I had some problems (though not the one you describe) until I did VS Installer / Repair on VS 2022 Preview.

Comment: I'm assuming you followed current instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation). You can also download [my MauiApp1 repo](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/MauiApp1). This was made using current "Maui" project template. Tested on Windows and Android. See if that builds for you.

Comment: Had some strange errors sometimes but like @ToolmakerSteve i used, VS Installer / Repair on VS 2022 Preview and the errors where gone

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I think it had something to do with me cloning the MAUI project to my local machine and trying to build it (not having much success).  I think somewhere in my journey the MAUI SDK workload got updated to preview 12, and I think these have a dependency on newer version of Micrsoft.Extensions.* packages.  I copied the NuGet.config file from the MAUI project (has additional package sources) into the same folder as my .csproj file.  Then I executed a "dotnet restore projectName.csproj" command from that directory.  Everything started working after that.